# Is there a way to get a newer version of the linux-firmware project than the package in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: firmware, amdgpu

On Ubuntu 18.04, Ryzen 2500u laptop X360, 32gb RAM.

Multiple times a day my laptop crashes with errors in the journal that I've pasted at the end of this message [1] indicating an issue with amdgpu.

According to other messages on the net they have had some luck updating the AMDGPU firmware blob, which is available in the linux-firmware deb package [2].

However, they did this by downloading the files from the git repo of the linux-firmware project [3] and copying them into the directory /lib/firmware/amdgpu  overwriting files provided by the deb package.

Is there a better way I can get these amdgpu firmware blobs without conflicting with the installed linux-firmware deb ?

[2] https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/linux-firmware

[3] https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/

(See the amdgpu directory)

These crashes seem pretty common on similar hardware - googling   Ryzen 2500u crash linux   shows many other people with the same problem.

[1]

> Jul 16 14:28:09.687981 computer kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [gfxhub]
> VMC page fault (src_id:0 ring:24 vmid:3 pasid:32768)
>
> Jul 16 14:28:09.688191 computer kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0:   at page
> 0x0000000104e07000 from 27
>
> Jul 16 14:28:09.688418 computer kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0:
> VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
>
> Jul 16 14:28:09.688637 computer kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [gfxhub]
>
> VMC page fault (src_id:0 ring:24 vmid:3 pasid:32768)
>
> Jul 16 14:28:09.688849 computer kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0:   at page
> 0x0000000104e05000 from 27
>
> Jul 16 14:28:09.689070 computer kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0:
> VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
>
> Jul 16 14:28:19.774250 computer kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout
> [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, last signaled seq=480375, last
> emitted seq=480378

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much better this is but you could try downloading and installing the debian sid package using `dpkg -i`

https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/firmware-amd-graphics/download

Answer (score 0):

The latest Debian package is currently out of date, too. (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=906526) So, I just suggest overwriting the files manually.  Eventually the package will update and overwrite your changes, but *probably* not until after they pull in new versions.